# How to fix size with fix-cm command?

Tags: fonts

I need to put the size of a word or some words to be 90pt, and I need to use fix-cm command, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You may select the fontsize explicitly via `\fontsize{<fontsize>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont`.  *Important:* Only use this to access non-standard sizes (such as 90pt) and use the normal scaling commands (`\tiny`, `\small`, `\large`, etc.) whenever possible!

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{90pt}{110pt}\selectfont Overfull hbox of doom
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: can I also use this to put Times font family on certain word?

Comment: @AganovićIrma Yes, just change the font to Times.  This is best done by using `\usepackage{newtxtext}` (the matching math font can be loaded with `\usepackage{newtxmath}`).  Note, that `fix-cm` is superfluous then, because this only applys to the Computer Modern (abbr.: CM) fonts.

Comment: note that if this is interspersed with other text (in a smaller size), it's necessary to end the "odd sized" text with `\par` or a blank line to make sure that the correct baseline is applied.  if that's omitted, and the larger text is enclosed in a group or a box, the baseline of the surrounding text will be applied, and although the larger text won't be overprinted, those lines will be squashed together with only a point or so of space between.

Comment: @AganovićIrma If you like my solution, please consider upvoting and marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852).